# difference between compiler, linker and debugger in c++

Tags: c++

I am working on operating system assignment and stuck on a point that what is the difference between linker, compiler and debugger ?

Comment: Making the font bold doesn't make your question any better. It's all about content here.

Answer (score 3):

The compiler turns each source file into machine code (aka object code), but doesn't create an executable program.

The linker links together one or more object files to make an executable program.

The debugger allows you to examine the program while it's running, to help investigate why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

[Compiler, Assembler, Linker and Loader: A Brief Story](http://www.tenouk.com/ModuleW.html)

Whereas, [Debugger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugger) is a different beast compared to the above.

A lot of information is already available on this topic. Just use your favorite search engine :)

Answer (score 0):

Very roughly, the compiler converts from human-readable source code into (almost) machine-runnable object code, and the linker joins up all the different sections of object code (and external libraries) to form a complete program.

The debugger is totally separate. It lets the programmer analyse what's happening when the program runs, with the aim of tracking down mistakes and errors.